# SpecFlow - Repeat test X times with list?

Tags: specflow

```
Scenario: Change a member to ABC 60 days before anniversary date
    Given Repeat When+Then for each of the following IDs:
    | ID         |
    | 0047619101 |
    | 0080762602 |
    | 0186741901 |
    | 0311285102 |
    | 0570130101 |
    | 0725968201 |
    | 0780265749 |
    | 0780265750 |
    | 0780951340 |
    | 0780962551 |
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    When these events occur:
    | WorkflowEventType   | WorkflowEntryPoint |
    | ABC                 | Status Change      | 
    Then these commands are executed:
    | command name      |
    | TerminateWorkflow |
    And For Member, the following documents were queued:
    | Name       |
    | ABC Packet |
```

In the above scenario I would like to:

- **GIVEN** - Lookup 10 members from the DB
- **WHEN + THEN** - Do these steps 10 times, once for each record.

Is this possible with SpecFlow?
If so, how would you set it up?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to do, although the documentation takes a bit of searching.

What you want is a scenario outline, like so:

```
Scenario Outline: Change a member to ABC 60 days before anniversary date
Given I have <memberId>
When these events occur:
    | WorkflowEventType   | WorkflowEntryPoint |
    | ABC                 | Status Change      | 
Then these commands are executed:
    | command name      |
    | TerminateWorkflow |
And For <memberId>, the following documents were queued:
    | Name       |
    | ABC Packet |

Examples: 
    | memberId   |
    | 0047619101 |
    | 0080762602 |
    | 0186741901 |
    | ...etc...  |
```

This will execute your scenario once for each id in the examples table.  You can extend the table to have multiple columns, if needed.

Or, more simply (if you really only have one row in each of your example tables above)

```
Scenario Outline: Change a member to ABC 60 days before anniversary date
Given I have <memberId>
When A 'ABC' Event Occurs with EntryPoint 'Status Change'
Then a TerminateWorkflow command is executed
And For <memberId>, the 'ABC Packet' document was queued

Examples: 
    | memberId   |
    | ...etc...  |
```

For more information see the [specflow-wiki on github](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow) and the [cucumber language syntax for scenario outlines](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines)

Comment: Thanks.  I finally did find this little nugget and it is AWESOME!

Comment: Also, we are using tables to help make the input more mutable.  We have probably 100 tests in this general form and some take multi-line inputs (in the table) while others are single line.  Again - thanks!